Why isn't my object following the bezier curve?
I'm trying to get my object to follow a bezier curve and for some reason it's not following it exactly. I followed this youtube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5YwrUTUAV0 and it seems to almost work. I did see some similar questions and made sure both the object and the curve are set to the same origin point. Is anyone able to help me or point me towards a tutorial that may help? For context, I'm fairly new and looking to create 3d renderings of different retail packaging types.
Thank you for any help! 

Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

@moonboots here is the file:  I'm still very new and teaching myself so I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Your curve is rotated, see if I display the local orientation, as I suppose that you want to keep it standing up, apply the rotation (CtrlA) and the rope will follow correctly:


you are my hero! That worked! Thank you so much!
